# collision of two masses separated by a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, collision

We are given two bodies of mass $m$ and $M$.  Mass $m$ is traveling to the right(towards $M$) with a given initial velocity **v**. We are also given that the collision is ellastic. The question is to calculate the maximum compression of the spring.

One way to do this would be to write conservation of energy and then notice that at the maximum compression of the spring, the speeds of the two bodies are the same. (  as this a maximum (minimum point) we have $\dfrac {x_M}{dt}$-$\dfrac{x_m}{dt}$)=0, so the velocities are equal).

My questions are: 
1) How can we make this observation in a more natural way? ( i would probably never think about taking that derivative initially unless I had some intuitive guess)
2) My way of solving it would be to write 2 second order ODE's for the movement of the bodies ( this would also describe the movement in general,right?) in the center of mass frame of reference and then take  the derivative of the difference of the coordinates $x_M'-x_m'$, equate 0.
We also have that $x_m'=x_M'*c$ where c is a constant depending on M,m ( because the center of mass is fixed, so we use here conservation of momentum).

There are two main problems:

It seems to me that the elastic force would act to the left on the m body and to the right on the M body (is this correct?how would we write the equations?). We have also the initial $X_m' and x_M'$ at t=0, but this only suffices for finding one constant of integration for each body, and we have two of them as the movement should be something like a*cos+b*sin

Comment: It is unclear where is the spring. I guess is initially in contact with M  and eventually m compresses it. If that is the case, why you do not just try conservation of momentum and of mechanical energy? you do not need the details of the dynamics to solve it.

Comment: Is this a one dimensional collision?  If so the answer to your first question is that when $v_m>v_M$ the distance between them is decreasing.  When $v_m<v_M$ the distance between them is increasing.  The distance is at a minimum between these two cases when $v_m=v_M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Sorry for the confusion. The spring is indeed attached to M and the collision is 1d                                                                                               I see. It works this way, yes (conservation of momentum and energy).  Let s say now that  I want to determine the precise dynamics of movement. How would I write the ODE s? And how would I use the fact that this is an ellastic collision? ( am i already using it when i write down the equations?)

Comment: You have not written any equations for the motion. Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You must apply both conservation of energy and momentum.

At maximum compression both masses are travelling at the same velocity. If this were not so they would get closer together or further apart. You can find this speed using conservation of momentum.

Then you can apply conservation of energy to find by how much the total KE has been reduced from its initial value. The difference is the elastic PE stored in the spring.